# STM32 (C) Trouble passing string literals and variables to a function in one go

Tags: c, string, pointers, stm32

I have a function that takes a pointer to a some data i.e.

```
void TxData(uint8_t *outString)
{
     // Do something.
}
```

Currently I am passing a mix of string literals and variables (all ascii data) to the function. E.G.

```
TxData((uint8_t *) "Setting");
TxData((uint8_t *) Info1);
TxData((uint8_t *) "=");
TxData((uint8_t *) Info2);
TxData((uint8_t *) "\r");
```

This all works but I wonder if I can do this in one line of code (i.e. something like concatenate so I only call `TxData` once). I don't want to do anything that will impact performance as this is a fairly low end Microcontroller (so don't want the strings to be copied) but want to tidy the code.

Comment: Just a sequence of `strcat()` (or a version that returned a pointer to the end of the appended string) would do the job?

Comment: @KenY-N All that achieves is to create a spike in stack space use and make the code less readable than what the OP currently got... so don't do that.

Comment: "This all works but I wonder if I can do this in one line of code" That's a nonsense "meta" requirement. Ask yourself what problem does "one line of code" solve. Calling the function in a loop would make more sense.

Answer (score 3):

> low end Microcontroller (so don't want the strings to be copied)

Then keep it as it is. You can also write the function which will take an array of `char *`.

```
const char * const toprint[] = {"Setting" ,Info1, "=", Info2, "\r", NULL};

void myTcData(const char * const ptr[])
{
    while(*ptr)
    { 
          TxData(*ptr);
          ptr++;
    }
}
```

It will not waste any precious RAM memory and the table will be kept in the FLASH.

I would also change the prototype of the `TxData`

```
void TxData(const void *ptr)
{
    const uint8_t *outstring = ptr;
    /* .... */
}
```

Comment: Why change the prototype to `void`? All you achieve with that is worse type safety. Keeping strings as `uint8_t` in a MCU is perfectly fine. Casting between `char` and `uint8_t` is safe and well-defined.

Comment: @Lundin Simply - to silence the warnings (signes)

Comment: `const char* mystr; ... TxData(&mystr);` Nice, no warnings!

Comment: @Lundin I have no clue what you mean but.  https://godbolt.org/z/1c9fMGqGb It is an issue with HAL libraries.

Comment: I mean that by making the parameter `void*` you got no error upon the incorrect use example I just posted. Better to keep it as `const uint8_t*` and then force the caller to cast when necessary.

Comment: So is the conclusion that I should use......
`void TxData(const void *outString)`
I.E. simply adding const?